# Is it possible to use FFT to derive a Fourier series fitting to data?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fast-fourier-transform

I want to do something like what is done [in this question about fitting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/using-fourier-analysis-to-fit-function-to-data) , ie find a Fourier series that approximates a continuous but complicated function. However I want to know whether it is possible to use the FFT for it.

Now to be precise my function is the ecliptic longitude of a celestial body. This function isn't periodic in the sense that it has an overall trend (the longitude keeps increasing overall) but I figure it is possible to factor out the straight line trend as suggested in [this USNA page](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/time6h9j.htm) and use the Fourier series just to cover the minor variations from it.

Now I am not formally trained in college-level mathematics (I'm formally in the humanities) but I have been reading around. Especially on this site I have read [this question asking for the difference between Fourier series and transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221137/what-is-the-difference-between-fourier-series-and-fourier-transformation) and [this one about how to use a transform to find the series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707150/use-fourier-transform-to-find-fourier-series-coeficcients) and understand the contents to a certain extent.

Now [the USNA page](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/time6h9j.htm) doesn't say exactly how to derive the Fourier series. I don't have access to MatLab to just do `fit(t',Y,'fourier8')` as suggested in [the first-mentioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29198/using-fourier-analysis-to-fit-function-to-data). However I am seeing many OSS libraries which have the FFT. Is it possible to derive a Fourier series using such an FFT? How?

[The last-mentioned question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707150/use-fourier-transform-to-find-fourier-series-coeficcients) seems to provide a method but the mathematical notation is higher than my comprehension limit so I'd appreciate simpler instructions.